# Running out of space on d2.2xlarge

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr

I launched a `d2.2xlarge` instance though EMR. These instances are supposed to have 12TB, but I'm getting a "No space left on device" error after downloading a few GB. I thought all this storage space was on the root drive, not EBS, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Here's what I see:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         30G   92K   30G   1% /dev
tmpfs            30G     0   30G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1      9.8G  9.7G     0 100% /
/dev/xvdb1      5.0G   44M  5.0G   1% /emr
/dev/xvdb2      1.9T  231M  1.9T   1% /mnt
/dev/xvdc       1.9T   34M  1.9T   1% /mnt1
/dev/xvdd       1.9T   34M  1.9T   1% /mnt2
/dev/xvde       1.9T   34M  1.9T   1% /mnt3
/dev/xvdf       1.9T   34M  1.9T   1% /mnt4
/dev/xvdg       1.9T   34M  1.9T   1% /mnt5
```

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=232806  -- There is a discussion on the same. Seems a like a timeout.

Comment: Run `df -h` to see what's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear when you encountered your out of space problems, but it sounds like it happens when you manually download something, not when using Hadoop. So I'll use that as basis for the explanation below.

Each Hadoop node will always have a [10GB root volume](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=217233). Additionally, depending on the instance type and configuration, it might have ephemeral volumes and/or EBS volumes to increase storage space. These volumes don't increase the size of the root partition, but are mounted to different paths!

As you mentioned, your `d2.2xlarge` comes with 6x 2TB of ephemeral storage, which are mounted to several mount points named `/mnt*`, as can be seen in your `df`-output. So if you need to manually download and store large data, store it under one of these mount points.

Be aware that all storage volumes, be it ephemeral storage or EBS volumes, [are considered ephemeral](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-storage.html) in AWS EMR:

> Amazon EBS works differently within Amazon EMR than it does with regular Amazon EC2 instances. Amazon EBS volumes attached to EMR clusters are ephemeral: the volumes are deleted upon cluster and instance termination (for example, when shrinking instance groups), so it's important that you not expect data to persist.

So no matter what you plan to do with the available storage in EMR, if you manually save data to one of the volumes, it will be lost sooner or later!

As EMR is a managed Hadoop solution it of course needs to provide a way to reliably store data. There is Hadoop's [HDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html) which, as a distributed file system, utilizes the available volumes and ensures data is available by saving multiple replicas of the data. On EMR HDFS uses available ephemeral storage volumes as well as EBS volumes attached to the instances. Even with HDFS you'll loose the data once you tear down the EMR cluster!

Real persistent storage of data can be achieved by storing it in S3, which is [supported by upstream Hadoop](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3), or with a proprietary solution by AWS only included in EMR called [EMRFS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-fs.html) which offers some advantages over the upstream solution.

So the usual process is to only store data manually on the volumes of a Hadoop node for tools you need to set up your Hadoop environment, use S3 or some streaming solution for your input data, HDFS during the processing of your data by Hadoop as an intermediate location and S3 for persisting the finished results.

Comment: Thanks, in my use case I only needed to temporarily store data on these instances before transferring to S3. I realized that I simply had to `cd` to `/mnt*` and then run the download script from there.

Answer (score 1):

From [Now available: D2 instances, the latest generation of Amazon EC2 Dense-storage instances](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/03/now-available-d2-instances-the-latest-generation-of-amazon-ec2-dense-storage-instances/)

The storage is instance storage (they are mounted and disappear when you stop the instance). The entire 12 TB is not on root, it is mounted as 6 disks.

[image]

Comment: I'm not stopping the instance, though. The data that was downloaded is still there.

Comment: I was just mentioning the storage is instance store which doesn't persist after a stop. The entire 12 TB is not on root, it is mounted as 6 disks.

Comment: Ah, so I need to mount each disk? Actually, it appears to already be mounted. So how do I get the data to write there?

Comment: You don't have to mount but you can only access it through /mnt, /mnt1 or creating a softlink from root.